# Python in Excel - importing own modules

Tags: python, excel

I just started with the new Python in Excel (only for Beta Channel so far).

Standard libraries seem to work fine, but I cannot import my own modules.
I tried to specify the path via "sys.path.append" or ".insert" but still getting the ModuleNotFoundError.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this depends on what libs are available/collected within Anaconda's Distribution for Python. I'd say this is probably available in their documentation? Doubt this would include personal modules.

Comment: Are you sure this is supported at all? Your Python script doesn't run locally after all

Comment: ^^^^^^^ Highly likely this use case is not feasible.

Comment: Well idk if this is possible, perhaps not. So is there any "clean" workaround or do I have to rewrite all the functions from my modules? :)

Comment: Python in Excel runs in an Anaconda environment "in the cloud" . I suspect the environment is shared among users. If you check [Anaconda's Text Analytics example](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/introduction-to-text-analysis-with-python-in-excel) you'll see that you can't even download stopwords. This isn't a Jupyter Excel product, it's targeted to "less advanced users" which I guess means people that don't already use one of Azure's data science services.